# How to post back a complex group of radio buttons

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

As it stands, users are able to select every radio button as the attribute `name` is unique for every radio button. Is there any way possible to treat each `Employee` as its own radio button group? i.e. Employee[0] can only select either Yes or No - **Not both.**

The reason I've chose to go with this naming convention, is because it works well with binding on post back to a List.

```
 <input name="Employees[0].Yes" value=Yes type="radio">
 <input name="Employees[0].No" value=No type="radio">

 <input name="Employees[1].Yes" value=Yes type="radio">
 <input name="Employees[1].No" value=No type="radio">

 <input name="Employees[2].Yes" value=Yes type="radio">
 <input name="Employees[2].No" value=No type="radio">

 <input name="Employees[3].Yes" value=Yes type="radio">
 <input name="Employees[3].No" value=No type="radio">
```

Comment: The "grouping" of radio buttons is done by the name attribute. Same name means same "group"

Comment: Your properties make no sense. It seems you want a `bool` property (and that you want to use radio buttons rather that a checkbox). You code needs to be `<input name="Employees[0].YourBoolProperty" value="True" type="radio">` and `<input name="Employees[0].YourBoolProperty" value="False" type="radio">` (but why in the world are you not using the `@Html.RadioButtonFor()` method?)

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this?

```
 <input name="Employees[0]" value=Yes type="radio">
 <input name="Employees[0]" value=No type="radio">

 <input name="Employees[1]" value=Yes type="radio">
 <input name="Employees[1]" value=No type="radio">

 <input name="Employees[2]" value=Yes type="radio">
 <input name="Employees[2]" value=No type="radio">

 <input name="Employees[3]" value=Yes type="radio">
 <input name="Employees[3]" value=No type="radio">
```

Comment: The actual code is a little more complex than the one posted, if this approach is taken - List<Employee> returns a list of null employees. However, with this approach - I suspect on postback it wouldn't know which radio button belongs to what property.